# How to use cocoapod to easily install react Mapbox GL React Native and other native components?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, react-native, mapbox-gl

I try to install [MapboxGL React Native component](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/blob/master/ios/install.md) the easy way with Cocoapod. I have never done that before and the readme.md is not very detailed.

I did:

```
$ react-native init AwesomeProject
$ cd AwesomeProject
$ npm install react-native-mapbox-gl --save
```

then I created a `Podspec`file at the root of the RN project with `pod 'RCTMapboxGL', :path => 'node_modules/react-native-mapbox-gl/ios'` 
and run `pod install`

But I have en error `[!] No 'Podfile' found in the project directory` so where do I need to put the Podfile and what do I need to put inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podspecs are files that specify how to integrate a pod and its metadata. You need to create a file named `Podfile`, not `Podspec`. You can also run `pod init` to create an empty one from the basic template.

Comment: so the Podspec file is a typo? Do I need to put 'node_modules/react-native-mapbox-gl/ios' in the Podfile ?

Comment: Yes, it's a typo, it's Podfile.